# Finiteness of morphism of curves with fixed image

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry

This question comes from the proof of "bend and break" lemma in "Higer-dimensional algebraic geometry" (p.59-60). I use the notations in compatible with the notation given there for convenience.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, and let $C$ be a smooth curve over an algebraically closed field of character 0. Suppose there is a nonconstant morphism $f: C \to X$, and we choose a fixed point $c \in C$.

Let $ Mor(C, X\mid g:c\mapsto g(c))$ be the moduli space of morphisms from $C \to X$ with $c$ has fixed image $f(c)$, and let $T \subset Mor(C, X\mid g:c\mapsto g(c))$be a one dimensional subvariety (suppose it exists). We use $\bar{T}$ to denote a smooth compatification of $T$.

Because $T$ is a subvariety of moduli space, there is an evaluation morphism, and hence we have a map $$ev: C \times \bar{T} -\to C \times T \to X.$$ Suppose we can extend this map $ev: C \times \bar{T} -\to X$ to be a morphism, we wish to get a contradiction in the following setting:

(1) $C$ is not $\mathbb{P}^1$.

(2) The image of ev is in the curve $f(C)$, i.e.  ev($C \times \bar{T}$)$=f(C)$.

According to the argument in the proof, because there is only finite automorprisms of $C$ (elliptic curve by Hartshorne IV Cor.4.7, higher genus by Hurwitz formula), there are only finite $t \in \bar{T}$, such that $ev(C,t) = f(C)$, and hence contradict the fact $\bar{T}$ is infinite.

However, I don't see how to show that "there are only finite $t \in \bar{T}$, such that $ev(C,t) = f(C)$".

Comment: This is not true if $C'=\mathbb P^1$. Take $c'=\infty$ and compose $f$ with the endomorphisms $z\mapsto z^n$ of $\mathbb P^1$, $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @Cantlog You are abosolutely right! That's why I wrote "$C$ is not a rational curve". Besides, I feel the result should still true without fixing points when $g(C) > 1$.

Comment: I meant you need to assume that $C'$ is not rational. In my example, take any $C$ (positive genus) and any morphism $f : C\to \mathbb P^1$, then compose with some endomorphisms of $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you!

Comment: In fact I think you should take the genus to be $>1$. If $C=C'$ is an elliptic curve, then the multiplication-by-m maps are nonconstant and fix the origin.

Comment: Yeah... I agree, this question comes from the proof of "bend and break" lemma in "Higer-dimensional algebraic geometry" (p.59-60). I changed a little bit to avoid background material, but I might changed too much. I will try to correct my statement.